# How do I create a constraint in Oracle to avoid duplicate values?

Tags: sql, oracle, field, constraints

I have to create a constraint that will prevent anyone from adding a row to the table that contains a duplicate email address, although null values are allowed in the email address column.

The table is already made, and I know how to create a basic check constraint.

How would I go through this without using a sub-query? (because I cannot use them in constraints :()

```
ALTER TABLE EMPS
ADD CONSTRAINT EMPSEMAIL_ALREADYEXISTS CHECK (EMAIL IS NULL AND ???);
```

SQL Command to obtain all the emails from the EMPS

```
SELECT EMAIL FROM EMPS;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a check constraint you need a unique index:

```
create unique index ix_email on EMPS (email);
```

Oracle does not include tuples in an index where all columns are NULL. in this case there is only a single column, so NULL values won't be indexed

Other DBMS don't allow more than one NULL value for a unique index like that

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was over complicating the question with requiring a CHECK. Question solved! :)